# How to reload a clojure file in REPL

Tags: clojure, reload, read-eval-print-loop, leiningen

What is the preferred way of reloading functions defined in a Clojure file without having to restart the REPL. Right now, in order to use the updated file I have to:

- edit `src/foo/bar.clj`
- close the REPL
- open the REPL
- `(load-file "src/foo/bar.clj")`
- `(use 'foo.bar)`

In addition, `(use 'foo.bar :reload-all)` does not result in required effect, which is evaluating the modified bodies of functions and returning new values, instead of behaving as the source haven't changed at all.

**Documentation:**

- [load-file](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/load-file)
- [use](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/use)

Comment: `(use 'foo.bar :reload-all)` has always worked fine for me. Also, `(load-file)` should never be necessary if you have your classpath set up right. What is the "required effect" you're not getting?

Comment: Yes, what is the "required effect"? Post a sample `bar.clj` detailing on the "required effect".

Comment: By required effect I meant that if I had a function `(defn f [] 1)` and I changed its definition to `(defn f [] 2)`, it seemed to me that after I issue `(use 'foo.bar :reload-all)` and call the `f` function it should return 2, not 1. Unfortunately it doesn't work that way for me and every time I change the body of function I have to restart the REPL.

Comment: You must have another problem in your setup... `:reload` or `:reload-all` should both work.

Comment: Will you post a transcript of your REPL?

Answer (score 226, accepted):

Or
`(use 'your.namespace :reload)`

Comment: `:reload-all` should also work. The OP specifically says it doesn't, but I think there was something else wrong in the OP's dev environment because for a single file the two (`:reload` and `:reload-all`) should have the same effect.

Here's the full command for `:reload-all`:
`(use 'your.namespace :reload-all)`

This reloads all the dependencies, too.

Answer (score 83):

There is also an alternative like using [tools.namespace](https://github.com/clojure/tools.namespace), it's pretty efficient:

```
user=> (use '[clojure.tools.namespace.repl :only (refresh)])

user=> (refresh)

:reloading (namespace.app)

:ok
```

Comment: this answer is more proper

Comment: Caveat: running `(refresh)` seems to also cause the REPL to forget that you've required `clojure.tools.namespace.repl`. Subsequent calls to `(refresh)` will give you a RuntimeException, "Unable to resolve symbol: refresh in this context." Probably the best thing to do is to either `(require 'your.namespace :reload-all)`, or, if you know you're going to want to refresh your REPL a lot for a given project, [make a `:dev` profile and add `[clojure.tools.namespace.repl :refer (refresh refresh-all)]` to `dev/user.clj`](http://thinkrelevance.com/blog/2013/06/04/clojure-workflow-reloaded).

Comment: Blogpost on the Clojure workflow by the author of tools.namespace: http://thinkrelevance.com/blog/2013/06/04/clojure-workflow-reloaded

Answer (score 72):

Reloading Clojure code using `(require … :reload)` and `:reload-all` is [very problematic](https://github.com/clojure/tools.namespace#reloading-code-motivation):

> - If you modify two namespaces which depend on each other, you must
>     remember to reload them in the correct order to avoid compilation
>     errors.
> - If you remove definitions from a source file and then reload it,
>     those definitions are still available in memory. If other code
>     depends on those definitions, it will continue to work but will
>     break the next time you restart the JVM.
> - If the reloaded namespace contains `defmulti`, you must also reload
>     all of the associated `defmethod` expressions.
> - If the reloaded namespace contains `defprotocol`, you must also
>     reload any records or types implementing that protocol and replace
>     any existing instances of those records/types with new instances.
> - If the reloaded namespace contains macros, you must also reload any
>     namespaces which use those macros.
> - If the running program contains functions which close over values in
>     the reloaded namespace, those closed-over values are not updated.
>     (This is common in web applications which construct the "handler
>     stack" as a composition of functions.)

The clojure.tools.namespace library improves the situation significantly. It provides an easy refresh function that does smart reloading based on a dependency graph of the namespaces.

```
myapp.web=> (require '[clojure.tools.namespace.repl :refer [refresh]])
nil
myapp.web=> (refresh)
:reloading (myapp.web)
:ok
```

Unfortunately reloading a second time will fail if the namespace in which you referenced the `refresh` function changed. This is due to the fact that tools.namespace destroys the current version of the namespace before loading the new code.

```
myapp.web=> (refresh)

CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: refresh in this context, compiling:(/private/var/folders/ks/d6qbfg2s6l1bcg6ws_6bq4600000gn/T/form-init819543191440017519.clj:1:1)
```

You could use the fully qualified var name as a workaround for this problem but personally I prefer not having to type that out on each refresh. Another problem with the above is that after reloading the main namespace the standard REPL helper functions (like `doc` and `source`) are no longer referenced there.

To solve these issues I prefer to create an actual source file for the user namespace so that it can be reliably reloaded. I put the source file in `~/.lein/src/user.clj` but you can place in anywhere. The file should require the refresh function in the top ns declaration like this:

```
(ns user
  (:require [clojure.tools.namespace.repl :refer [refresh]]))
```

You can setup [a leiningen user profile](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md) in `~/.lein/profiles.clj` so that location you put the file in is added to the class path. The profile should look something like this:

```
{:user {:dependencies [[org.clojure/tools.namespace "0.2.7"]]
        :repl-options { :init-ns user }
        :source-paths ["/Users/me/.lein/src"]}}
```

Note that I set the user namespace as the entry point when launching the REPL. This ensures that the REPL helper functions get referenced in the user namespace instead of the main namespace of your application. That way they won’t get lost unless you alter the source file we just created.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Good suggestions.  One question: why the ":source-paths" entry above?

Comment: OK, found the answer.  The file "user.clj" needs to live somewhere, and a good place is "/home/alan/.lein/user.clj" (on linux).  For lein to find the file, we need a file "/home/alan/.lein/profiles.clj " with an entry like: ':source-paths [ "/home/alan/.lein"  '

Comment: Exactly, having an actual source file makes it possible to reliably reload that file and the namespace within. Here is the file I'm currently using: https://github.com/Dirklectisch/.lein/blob/master/src/user.clj

Comment: @fl00r Sorry not quite getting your point. It should be :source-paths in this case since we are loading source files not other resources.

Comment: @DirkGeurs, with `:source-paths` I get `#<FileNotFoundException java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate user__init.class or user.clj on classpath: >`, while with `:resource-paths` everything is ok.

Comment: @fl00r Have you created the source file user.clj? "To solve these issues I prefer to create an actual source file for the user namespace so that it can be reliably reloaded."

Comment: Yes I did. Now it is stored in `~/.lein/user/user.clj` with other stuff

Comment: @fl00r and it still throws that error? Do you have a valid project.clj in the folder you are launching the REPL from? That might fix your problem.

Comment: Yes, it is pretty standard, and all works fine with `:resource-paths`, I am in my user namespace inside repl.

Comment: if that's the case, then the clojure repl really sucks.

Comment: I'm doing a tutorial. Is it ok if I `reload-all` there?

Comment: @Alper Yes you will probably be alright or at least you will notice soon enough if you hit one of the cases described above.

Comment: I just had a great time working with a REPL that was lying to me because of this `reload` issue. Then it turned out everything I thought was working was not anymore. Maybe somebody should fix this situation?

Comment: @Alper I don't think they will address this any time soon in the language. `tools.namespace` is you best bet. Cool to hear that you are trying out Clojure. There is a lot to love there.

Comment: Hey! It seems like that and now that I got setup with Calva at a basic level things are looking up.

Comment: Can ```tools.namespace``` helps somehow to reimport recompiled Java classes as well?

Comment: @fl00r Seems ```:source-paths``` indeed cause an error when ```lein repl``` called in folder without project.clj (while ```:resource-paths``` does not)

Answer (score 54):

The best answer is:

```
(require 'my.namespace :reload-all)
```

This will not only reload your specified namespace, but will reload all dependency namespaces as well.

**Documentation:**

[require](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/require)

Comment: This is the only answer which worked with `lein repl`, Coljure 1.7.0 and nREPL 0.3.5. If you're new to clojure: The namespace (`'my.namespace`) is defined with `(ns ...)` in `src/`...`/core.clj`, for example.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that the original question is using (load-file ...), no require. How can her add the :reload-all to the namespace after the load-file?

Comment: Because the namespace structure like `proj.stuff.core` mirrors the file structure on disk like `src/proj/stuff/core.clj`, the REPL can locate the correct file and you don't need `load-file`.

Answer (score 7):

One liner based on papachan's answer:

```
(clojure.tools.namespace.repl/refresh)
```

Answer (score 5):

I use this in Lighttable (and the awesome instarepl) but it should be of use in other development tools. I was having the same problem with old definitions of functions and multimethods hanging around after reloads so now during development instead of declaring namespaces with:

```
(ns my.namespace)
```

I declare my namespaces like this:

```
(clojure.core/let [s 'my.namespace]
                  (clojure.core/remove-ns s)
                  (clojure.core/in-ns s)
                  (clojure.core/require '[clojure.core])
                  (clojure.core/refer 'clojure.core))
```

Pretty ugly but whenever I re-evaluate the entire namespace (Cmd-Shift-Enter in Lighttable to get the new instarepl results of each expression), it blows away all old definitions and gives me a clean environment. I was tripped up every few days by old definitions before I started doing this and it has saved my sanity. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try load-file again?

If youre using an IDE, there's usually a keyboard shortcut to send a code-block to the REPL, thus effectively re-defining the associated functions.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as `(use 'foo.bar)` works for you, it means that you have foo/bar.clj or foo/bar_init.class on your CLASSPATH.  The bar_init.class would be an AOT-compiled version of bar.clj.  If you do `(use 'foo.bar)`, I'm not exactly sure if Clojure prefers class over clj or the other way round.  If it would prefer class files and you have both files, then it's clear that editing the clj file and then reloading the namespace has no effect.

BTW: You don't need to `load-file` before the `use` if your CLASSPATH is set properly.

BTW2: If you need to use `load-file` for a reason, then you can simply do it again if you edited the file.

Comment: Not sure why this is marked as the correct answer. It doesn't answer the question clearly.

Comment: As someone coming to this question, I don't find this answer very clear.