# clojure classpath(?) troubles loading code and dependencies with leiningen

Tags: clojure, classpath, leiningen

I'm a Clojure and JVM beginner, and the build tools are a bit confusing to me, so forgive the stupidity I'm about to carry out.  I don't actually know what a "classpath" is... I just want a Lisp with lots of libraries!

But I'm trying to do a write a simple little bit of text-mining code in Clojure, and I don't seem to be able to get things working.

There are two problems, and I think they're related, both probably to this classpath thing from javaland that none of the introductory Clojure books seem to explain.

I started the project with `lein new` and my project.clj has the following dependencies:

```
 :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"] 
                 [clj-fuzzy "0.1.8"]
                 [snowball-stemmer "0.1.0"]
                 [net.mikera/core.matrix "0.50.0"]])
```

and the relevant ns call from my core.clj is as follows:

```
(ns blabber.core 
  (:require 
    [clojure.string :refer [lower-case split]]
    [clojure.walk :refer [keywordize-keys]]))
```

My directory structure is the default setup leiningen uses for a new library.

**First problem**:

I gather from this prior [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658981/how-to-reload-a-clojure-file-in-repl) that if things are set up right, I shouldn't need to call `(load-file "src/blabber/core.clj")` in the repl before calling `(use 'blabber.core)` in order to get at code I just wrote. (I'm firing up the lein repl from the src/blabber directory in bash). But when I fire up the repl, use fails unless I call load-file first.  So does that mean my classpath is set up wrong somehow?  And how does one fix such a thing?

**Second problem**:

Ok, so now I'm trying to actually use core.matrix.  First line of my core.clj changed to:

```
(ns blabber.core 
  (:require 
    [clojure.string :refer [lower-case split]]
    [clojure.walk :refer [keywordize-keys]]
    [clojure.core.matrix :refer [dataset]]))
```

When I first started the repl with this project.clj but without the `:require` to core.matrix, leiningen happily fetched core.matrix: `Retrieving net/mikera/core.matrix/0.50.0/core.matrix-0.50.0.jar from clojars`

However, after including the `:require` to core.matrix in the actual code and starting up the repl again, at the repl I call `(load-file "src/blabber/core.clj")`, and get the following error:

> CompilerException java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/core/matrix__init.class or clojure/core/matrix.clj on classpath: , compiling:(/Users/pauliglot/github/blabber/src/blabber/core.clj:1:1)

I'm using Leiningen 2.5.1 on Java 1.8.0_45.  And I'm just following the [getting started guide](https://github.com/mikera/core.matrix/wiki/Getting-Started-Guide) for core.matrix.

So what happened? Why can't the JVM find any of my stuff? Save me? Thanks!

If it helps, here's a dump of the output of `lein classpath`

> /Users/pauliglot/github/blabber/test:/Users/pauliglot/github/blabber/src:/Users/pauliglot/github/blabber/dev-resources:/Users/pauliglot/github/blabber/resources:/Users/pauliglot/github/blabber/target/classes:/Users/pauliglot/.m2/repository/clj-fuzzy/clj-fuzzy/0.1.8/clj-fuzzy-0.1.8.jar:/Users/pauliglot/.m2/repository/snowball-stemmer/snowball-stemmer/0.1.0/snowball-stemmer-0.1.0.jar:/Users/pauliglot/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.macro/0.1.5/tools.macro-0.1.5.jar:/Users/pauliglot/.m2/repository/clojure-complete/clojure-complete/0.2.3/clojure-complete-0.2.3.jar:/Users/pauliglot/.m2/repository/org/clojure/google-closure-library-third-party/0.0-20140226-71326067/google-closure-library-third-party-0.0-20140226-71326067.jar:/Users/pauliglot/.m2/repository/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.4.1/protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar:/Users/pauliglot/.m2/repository/org/clojure/google-closure-library/0.0-20140226-71326067/google-closure-library-0.0-20140226-71326067.jar:/Users/pauliglot/.m2/repository/org/mozilla/rhino/1.7R4/rhino-1.7R4.jar:/Users/pauliglot/.m2/repository/org/json/json/20090211/json-20090211.jar:/Users/pauliglot/.m2/repository/net/mikera/core.matrix/0.50.0/core.matrix-0.50.0.jar:/Users/pauliglot/.m2/repository/com/google/javascript/closure-compiler/v20131014/closure-compiler-v20131014.jar:/Users/pauliglot/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/Users/pauliglot/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojurescript/0.0-2202/clojurescript-0.0-2202.jar:/Users/pauliglot/.m2/repository/args4j/args4j/2.0.16/args4j-2.0.16.jar:/Users/pauliglot/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.nrepl/0.2.6/tools.nrepl-0.2.6.jar:/Users/pauliglot/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/15.0/guava-15.0.jar:/Users/pauliglot/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.6.0/clojure-1.6.0.jar:/Users/pauliglot/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.reader/0.8.3/tools.reader-0.8.3.jar:/Users/pauliglot/.m2/repository/org/clojure/data.json/0.2.3/data.json-0.2.3.jar

**Edit**
Here's the directory tree: 
  | blabber
   |-doc
   |-resources
   |-src
   |---blabber
   |-target
   |---classes
   |-----META-INF
   |-------maven
   |---------blabber
   |-----------blabber
   |---stale
   |-test

and all my code is in blabber/src/blabber/core.clj

Comment: A classpath is a Java concept; Leiningen should set up the classpath correctly.  What I suspect is that there's a mismatch between the directories, filenames, or namespace declarations.  The file path should be `<name passed to 'lein new'>/src/blabber/core.clj`.  It wasn't clear from what you wrote whether that's the case.  Try running `lein deps` first, too, but you shouldn't need to do that.  This and `lein repl` are usually run from the `<name passed to 'lein new'>` directory.   You might need `:source-paths` or `:main` in project.clj, but I don't think so.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the file path is right.  (blabber was the name passed to lein new... Im 95% sure.  wonder if there's a log somewhere to make sure?).  will try `lein deps` --- also editing to add the directory tree.

Comment: iiinteresting.  After running `lein deps` and starting the repl from the project root (name passed to lein new) directory, the repl can find my code, but it still can't find core matrix. `(use 'blabber.core)` throws `CompilerException java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/core/matrix__init.class or clojure/core/matrix.clj on classpath: , compiling:(blabber/core.clj:1:1)`

Comment: hmm.  I'm starting to suspect that this is a glitch in the docs for core.matrix, because I just started up a dummy project, listed `[net.mikera/core.matrix "0.50.0"]` as a dependency, and tried to simply `(use 'clojure.core.matrix)` from the repl, and it threw the same error. Or maybe I'm being an idiot in some obvious way...

Comment: This should work.  Works for me, e.g. with `(defproject blabber "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [net.mikera/core.matrix "0.50.0"]])`.  (FWIW, I bet that half of all new Clojure programmers go through similar growing pains.  I did.  Drove me crazy for the first week.  Then you figure out where the little obscure meta-gotchas are, and they never bother you again.)

Comment: Hmm... I wonder if it's just not compatible with clojure 1.6.0, which leiningen is currently feeding me.  I can get it to work in boot. with `(set-env! :dependencies '[[net.mikera/core.matrix "0.50.0"]])` then `(use 'clojure.core.matrix)`, but after the first call it goes and fetches clojure 1.8.0... hmm...

Comment: ah!  there it was!  changed the dep in projects.clj to 1.8.0 and it runs. Well, that was an anticlimactic solution.  Thanks for the clue in your dependencies list :-)

Comment: Great!  Sometimes it's only through a comment discussion that the real problem reveals itself.  I posted some of my remarks as an answer, and if you want, you can upvote it and/or accept it, but that's up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A classpath is a Java concept; Leiningen should set up the classpath correctly. What I suspect is that there's a mismatch between the directories, filenames, or namespace declarations. The file path should be `<name passed to 'lein new'>/src/blabber/core.clj.` It wasn't clear from what you wrote whether that's the case. Try running `lein deps` first, too, but you shouldn't need to do that. This and `lein repl` are usually run from the  directory, i.e. the project root directory. You might need `:source-paths` or `:main` in project.clj, but I don't think so.

`(use 'clojure.core.matrix)` should work. Works for me, e.g. with

```
(defproject blabber "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
  [net.mikera/core.matrix "0.50.0"]]).
```