# How to automatically reload Clojure code?

Tags: dynamic, clojure

How to automatically reload Clojure code?

I have watched [the presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dGVqrGmwOAw).  And in there they use some hot swap Clojure technology that reloads code whenever changes are made into source files. I can run the code, but I can not observe the effect of auto reload. How is it possible to reload the code?

[the source code.](https://gist.github.com/spacemanaki/1093917)

Comment: Have you tried [figwheel](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel)?

Comment: I asked a [question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/126376/82369) on Code Review about my Clojure workflow; you may find it useful.

Comment: Figwheel watches your cljs/cljc files, compiles them, then sends them to your browser to execute them. AFAIK it won't do much to reload server side code when you have a repl open (could be wrong though).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to reload code, depending on the situation:

- [Emacs/CIDER](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider) shortcuts to reload a file. Probably Rich is doing something similar. Also see this: [How to reload a clojure file in REPL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7658981/1327651)
- watch files and reload the code ([figwheel](https://github.com/bhauman/figwheel-template) for frontend development does that, [test plugins](https://github.com/jakemcc/lein-test-refresh) as well as CIDER shortcuts specifically for running tests, [boot](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot) has a `watch` task...)
- a middleware for the web server you use ([ring](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring) for example has `ring.middleware.reload/wrap-reload` for this, [pedestal](https://github.com/pedestal/samples/tree/master/auto-reload-server) comes with [one](https://github.com/pedestal/samples/tree/master/auto-reload-server) as well, other webservers like [`yada`](https://github.com/juxt/yada) play well with component)
- a [component](https://github.com/stuartsierra/component) workflow works also, there is an example of an auto-reloadable system with [holy-grail](https://github.com/danielsz/holygrail)

Answer (score 2):

(I didn't fully re-watch this video, but these notes are from my observations after skipping through the video and making educated guesses)

From what I re-watched of this video it looks like Rich is evaluating the code in a running repl. This allows him to change the code, evaluate it, and see different behavior.

Many editors have support for evaluating code in a buffer in a Clojure repl. [Here](https://cider.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactive_programming/) is some documentation on using CIDER with Emacs to get to interactively play with your code.

Unrelated to the video in question, if you are using [ring](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/) for web development. You can use the [wrap-reload](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/master/ring-devel/src/ring/middleware/reload.clj) middleware to have your code automatically reloaded when a file has changed and a request hits your web app. This is extremely useful when developing a Clojure web application.

For automatically reloading and running your clojure.tests I recommend [lein-test-refresh](https://github.com/jakemcc/lein-test-refresh). It is a Leiningen plug-in that monitors your project for file changes and when something changes it reloads and runs your tests. If you have tests for your project this greatly speeds up development.

Comment: I've been using lein-test-refresh myself, with much success! I often add some code in vim at the top level of my program (not inside a test or a function), save the file, see what prints out in the window with Leiningen, edit, save again, see what prints out, and so on. I figure stuff out pretty quickly this way, and then I just wrap it in a `defn` to make it part of the program.

Answer (score 2):

Use mount to manage the starting and stopping of your components.  For example in a backend web app, you'll want to startup the db before you start the webserver probably.

Then in emacs you can have:

```
(defun cider-repl-refresh ()
(interactive)
(save-some-buffers)
(with-current-buffer (cider-current-repl-buffer)
(goto-char (point-max))
(insert (concat "(require 'clojure.tools.namespace.repl) "
                "(clojure.tools.namespace.repl/refresh)"))
(cider-repl-return)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not super fond of Emacs (I love Emacs, but hey not everybody does) [LightTable](http://lighttable.com/) is a very nice option for Clojure/ClojureScript interactive programming too.

For developing ClojureScript (Clojure that compiles to Javascript) [LightTable](http://lighttable.com/) and [Figwheel](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel) are a really nice pair.

In my opinion LightTable has some advantages against Emacs (I never got cider to work perfectly with ClojureScript) for the webdev side, LightTable is basically a specialized version of Chrome, because it is built on top of [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/).

Check this documentation on the Figwheel GitHub page: [Running Figwheel with LightTable](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel/wiki/Running-figwheel-with-LightTable):

[image: LightTable + Fighweel]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cursive IDE in IntelliJ, there is a special REPL tool which you have to setup to get the functionality you are looking for. It has many features vs. "lein repl" in a terminal window.

Full tutorial here: https://cursive-ide.com/userguide/repl.html

However, its very easy to setup a default instance:

1. Right click project.clj/deps.edn -> "Create Repl for...". Default settings are fine. Hit ok/apply.
2. Right click project.clj/deps.edn -> "Run Repl for..." (a repl window will open)
3. See Tools->Repl for a list of commands, such as:

- switch to repl window: Ctrl+\
- reload current file in repl: Alt + Shift + L
- send function defn to repl: Alt + Shift + M
- ... and more

In addition you'll get full code completion, syntax highlighting, etc. when writing in a REPL.