# Automatically eval a dependent file (buffer)

Tags: clojure

I have a `clj` file which defines a schema. There are about 3 or 4 files that depend on the definition of that schema to generate functions. I would like it so that whenever the schema file changes, the dependent files are automatically reevaluated within the repl.

This is quite useful because re-evaluation is also needed when macros are changed. I've looked at `load-file` but I don't think it does the trick. Are there any suggestion of how might one go about doing this?

I want to manually trigger a commented out form in A.
Files B, C, D have a dependency on A. If A changes then B, C, D gets evaluated.

`:reload-all` does the reverse, ie. A has a dependency on B, C and D and will evaluate all it's dependents.

Comment: There's `(require ... :reload-all)` that might help

Comment: I don't think this works.

Comment: Right, `:reload-all` is sorta for the opposite problem: reloading all namespaces depended on by a particular namespace. The question is rather about reloading all namespaces that depend on a particular namespace, and in general this is not something the runtime keeps track of.

Answer (score 1):

I have a template project set up here:

- https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template

It uses the `lein-test-refresh` plugin so that changed files are automatically reloaded upon each editor save, and then all unit tests are re-run. IMHO this is even better (& faster!) than experimenting in the REPL.  The [Koacha](https://github.com/lambdaisland/kaocha) tool has similar capabilities.

You can also [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658981/how-to-reload-a-clojure-file-in-repl/25102248#25102248) re `:reload-all`.

Comment: I accepted an answer on the :reload-all but I don't think it works the way I've described. I've put more in the description. I think lein-test-refresh would work but I'd like to manually trigger it.